# X509Certificate2: determine if certificate private key belongs to an hardware device, and if it needs a PIN

Tags: c#, smartcard, x509certificate2

I'm writing a program to do encryption things, using certificates stored on hardware devices (smart cards).

- The program must use .Net Framework 4.5.2 :( Changing this isn't possible.
- The crypto things I perform haven't problems :)

***Preamble***

As far as I understood, when a smart card, containing one or more certificates, is connected to the computer, the certificates appears on the Windows certificates store (CurrentUser/My).

This is managed by the smartcard software, that must be installed.

Since my software must work with any hardware device, the easiest solution is to popup a window, and making the user to choose the certificate to use.

***First problem***

I don't want to show all the certificates that are on CurrentUser/My, but only the ones that have an associated hardware connected to the computer.

This is, more or less, the code that I'm using:

```
X509Store storeObject = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

storeObject.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (var certificate in storeObject.Certificates)
{
    bool isValid = false;
    if (certificate.HasPrivateKey)
    {
        try
        {
            var rsaKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
            
            if (rsaKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice)
            {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // just log
        }
    }
}
```

Despite this solution is very ugly, it's the best I came up.

The certificate belongs to a smart card if:

- HasPrivateKey is true.
- The cast of PrivateKey to RSACryptoServiceProvider didn't throw an exception if the smart card is connected.
- HardwareDevice then is true.

The problem is on the PrivateKey cast: it seems that lot of things are performed by the CryptoApi system during this cast (that includes calls - of course - to the smart card software).

This is **very slow**, and if the smartcard software has some kind of failures, uncontrollable error messages are shown, ...

***Question***

Is there any other way to determine if the certificate belongs to an hardware device?
And to determine if the hardware is currently connected?

***Second problem***

The certificate may require a PIN.

I must (it's a prerequisite) avoid the Windows input box asking for the PIN.

It's not a problem for me to collect the PIN, and to use it during my crypto operations.

My problem is to understand if the PIN is required or not.

ANY example I found online assume that if rsaKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice == true then a PIN is required.

But I'm not sure about that.

***Question***

Is there any way I can determine if a certificate requires a PIN code?

***Conclusion***

I also like external libraries, as long as they are free (preferably open source) and/or come from Microsoft.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use windows explorer to get card working the first time.  When you setup the driver a lot of these issues are automatically handled.  Read the vendor user manual.  Once the card is working with the explorer you can use it with c# code.  Windows explorer will unlock the card and then you can read and write.  Smart cards have different addressing modes and data sizes (8,16,32,64).  So make sure you can Write with windows and read with c# (and opposite).  Then write code to unlock in c#.  You need to know the sizes to be able to unlock the card.

Comment: `This is very slow` -- how slow? You may consider to use Win32 interop to query certificate properties, read provider name, then query provider info that tells whether the key is stored on a smart card or not.

Comment: @Crypt32 as slow as 2/3 seconds for each casting (certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider).
My problem isn't to get the certificate properties, except for PrivateKey, since the cast above sometimes (when the card isn't connected, or the smartcard software has troubles) give problems.
I was wondering if this was the only method to retreive the CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice property, and to understand if the card is connected.
I'll try with the Win32 interop, but I suspect I'll get the same results.

Comment: Properties I mean are not part of `X509Certificate2` object, they are not directly accessible from .NET API, they are available through Win32 interop.

Answer (score 1):

In comments I offered Win32 interop solution which may be faster than delay OP experiences. Proposed solution will extended certificate properties to read provider name from there (I believe, .NET does the same somewhere internally?). Then open specified provider (CSP or KSP) and query hardware capabilites from provider. This solution doesn't touch private key, nor prompt for PIN.

Call sequence:

1. Call [CertGetCertificateContextProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetcertificatecontextproperty) function and query `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` property.
2. Function returns you a pointer to a [CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/ns-wincrypt-crypt_key_prov_info) structure.
3. Structure contains `pwszProvName` field that stores provider name.
4. Call [NCryptOpenStorageProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptopenstorageprovider) function and pass provider name as a parameter.
5. Call [NCryptGetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptgetproperty) function and pass provider handle obtained in previous step and property name to retrieve. You need `NCRYPT_IMPL_TYPE_PROPERTY` property.
6. Received value will store a bitwise flag combination of implementation types. Check if returned value (`pbOutput` parameter will store 4 bytes integer value) has `NCRYPT_IMPL_HARDWARE_FLAG` flag enabled.

Release all unmanaged resources when calls are done. Although this looks a bit complicated, but from my experience this is the fastest way to determine where key is stored for a given certificate.

## Important remarks

steps 4 and 5 may not work for all smart card providers (given that you use legacy CSP), though, works for mine. In this case, replace steps 4 and 5 as follows:

4. Call [CryptAcquireContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptacquirecontexta) function to get a handle to your provider (retrieved in step 3)
5. call [CryptGetProvParam](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgetprovparam) function to retrieve provider properties. Query for `PP_IMPTYPE` property. `pbData` parameter will store a 4-byte long byte array that represents a bitwise combination of implementation types. Check if this value has `CRYPT_IMPL_HARDWARE1` flag enabled.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to put together the code for the first part of your suggestion, and it works like a charm. For the second part, I'm in trouble with the CryptAcquireContext()... Have you any clue for the dwProvType and dwFlags parameters?

Comment: `dwProvType` in `CryptAcquireContext` call matches the `dwProvType` in `CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO` returned in step 1. `dwFlags` parameter should be `CRYPT_SILENT`.

Comment: Thank you Crypt32, your help was priceless! I'll put the code below the question, as soon as possible (few days).